# <select> placeholder with Angular/Bootstrap not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I would like to have a select with a placeholder in Angularjs with bootstrap. The [solutions](http://jsfiddle.net/LXp4h/) I have found do not work with Angular

Here is my Angular markup:

```
<select ng-model="myModel" 
     ng-options="p.name for p in ..."
     class="form-control list-selector required">
   <option value='' disabled selected>Please Choose</option>
</select>
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to add an empty option to your select:

```
<option value="">- Please Choose -</option>
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/FShdc/

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle out of it so we can check?

Comment: You were right, it's working correctly. Thanks for you help! http://jsfiddle.net/unludo/jZS95/8/

Comment: 1 thing that was giving me problems is that the model of the select must be set to an empty string for this to work, I had it set to an empty object and it was creating an extra blank line in my options...hope this helps someone later :D

Comment: It doesn't help when the select ng-model is marked as required. Is there a way you can assign null value to this option so that form remains invalid?

Comment: is there any reason that it works with <option value=""></option> and not <option ng-value=""></option> ?

Comment: @DrCord Thanks that helped! However, I do need an `ng-model` on my select, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @BigMoney - I think you can still use `ng-model` on the select, see the jsfiddle.

Comment: @DianaNassar your response is correct, you should just add two more critical lines to your response, this might not be that clear for the beginners: `$scope.myModel = "";` that you set in the Controller, and `ng-model="myModel"` that you put in the html select statement. Again, great answer.

Comment: Thanks @Blejzer! A full working example is available in the JSFiddle that I reference in my answer. :)

Comment: I would add the attribute `disabled` so the user cannot return to the placeholder once an option is selected.

Answer (score 0):

For Angularjs Versions and reactive forms , if you are using ngValue to bind values in options , the following type of solution will work:

```
<option value='' selected ng-value="null">Please Choose</option>
```

For Angular 2+ Versions something like this will work-

```
<select class="form-control"
    formControlName="roomType" 
    (change)="changeRoomType($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="null" selected>Room Type</option>
    <option *ngFor="let room of roomTypes" [ngValue]="room">{{room}}</option>    
    </select>
```

For reference, check this link out-https://netbasal.com/angular-quick-tip-how-to-show-a-placeholder-in-select-control-bab688f98b98