# ng-options in angular placeholder

Tags: angularjs

I have a select box, Pretty basic, shown below

```
<div ng-if="field.field_type == 'select'">
<p><strong>{{field.field_name}}:</strong></p>
<div class="form_field"><label class="fontawesome-pencil" for="login_Custom"></label>
<div class="input-group col-xs-8">
<style media="screen">
    select:not([multiple]) {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        background-position: right 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
        padding: .5em;
        padding-right: 1.5em;
    }
</style>
<select class="selectpicker form-control" default-option="Test" name="cusdropdown" ng-model="testInfo" ng-options="i.val as (i.nam) for i in field.options" style="width:450px"></select> <span class="input-group-addon buttonlike" ng-click="removeRegistrationfield($index)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm wanting the `field.field_name` as the placeholder, I know how to do this in html, Which is like this

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose</option>
    <option value="0">Open when powered (most valves do this)</option>
    <option value="1">Closed when powered, auto-opens when power is cut</option>
</select>
```

However how can i do this inside angular?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you want this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158742/select-placeholder-with-angular-bootstrap-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-options` and add yourself a placeholder at the same time.

Duplicate : [<select> placeholder with angular/bootstrap not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158742/select-placeholder-with-angular-bootstrap-not-working)

Comment: Sorry i only just found it after posting the question!!